# how to continues netstat a port and save it to text file with time stamp for each netstat

Tags: netstat

I am using a system which is integrated to other system using a specific port and recently I am facing multiple interruption in the integration, and I need to monitor the port "48823" for a complete day and save it to a text file with time stamp for each netstat status as below example:

```
15/12/2022 13:37:00 TCP 10.10.10.150:48823  10.10.10.151:4003 Established
15/12/2022 15:22:10 TCP 10.10.10.150:48823  10.10.10.151:4003 Listening
15/12/2022 13:37:00 TCP 10.10.10.150:48823  10.10.10.151:4003 Time_wait
```

I tired the following command:
" netstat -na | find "48823" > c:\netstat.txt".  but it gives only the current status not a continuous one. Also it is not showing the date and time stamp

so appreciate if someone can help by sharing the correct command.

Comment: What you did so far?

Comment: I tried " netstat -na | find "48823" > c:\netstat.txt" but it gives only the current status not a continuous one. Also it is not showing the date and time stamp.

Comment: Add this to the question, not in comment